# Is the String args[] parameter needed for programs that do not require command line arguments?

Tags: java, command-line, program-entry-point

As far as I know, `String args[]` accepts an array of elements of type `String` - a mechanism through which the runtime system passes information to an application.

If we take a simple addition program like this:

```
class Add {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 30;
        int c = x + y;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

It is obvious that the program does not need any command line arguments to calculate the result. No values are passed to the args array. So, is it necessary to include this array or does the `main()` syntax requires us to do otherwise?

Comment: You don't in c#.  I'd say try it...

Comment: By "reasonable" do you mean "necessary"?

Comment: The main function *must* have that signature.

Comment: As has been stated, you can't change the method signature, but you can just ignore the contents (or lackthereof) of `args[]` assuming you don't need to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are **required** to have a function called `public static void main(String[] args)` as an entry point to your Java program.

If you look at the documentation for the actual [java command](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/java/), it makes it explicit:

> The **java** command starts a Java application. It does this by starting the Java Runtime Environment (JRE), loading the specified class, and calling that class's main() method. The method must be declared public and static, it must not
>          return any value, and it must accept a String array as a parameter. The method declaration has the following form:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
> ```

There is a difference between this and a JavaFX program; [its initial entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) is located in the `start()` function.

Comment: For the record, if you try to use the [varargs feature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), writing `public static void main(String... args)`, you'll see that that also works.

Answer (score 3):

From [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN):

> In the Java programming language, every application must contain a main method whose signature is:
>
> public static void main(String[] args)

Answer (score 2):

Yes - if you leave the arguments out, you will get the following error:

> Error: Main method not found in class nl.magnus.test.Test, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args)

This requirement for `main` is specified by Oracle in the [Java SE specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4):

> Finally, after completion of the initialization for class Test (during which other consequential loading, linking, and initializing may have occurred), the method main of Test is invoked.
>
> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of String. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:
>
> public static void main(String[] args)
>
> public static void main(String... args)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer - yes. Your `main` method must have a `String[]` parameter, even if it doesn't use it.

If it doesn't have such a parameter Java just treats it as any other `public static` method, not as the entry point of the program.

Answer (score 0):

That is the required definition of program entry point in Java. You have to have it.

Answer (score 0):

Its the syntax of the `main()` method, whether you send the runtime args or not from command line.

The execution of any program will only start with this signature of `main()` :-

```
public static void main(String args[])
```